Error.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'trainable' when try to load a .keras model
I've trained a NER model and save it as .keras file, when I try to load the model, it pops up this error
TypeError: <class 'modeling.NERModel'> could not be deserialized properly. Please ensure that components that are Python object instances (layers, models, etc.) returned 
by `get_config()` are explicitly deserialized in the model's `from_config()` method.

config={'module': 'modeling', 'class_name': 'NERModel', 'config': {'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32'}, 'registered_name': 'NERModel', 'build_config': {'input_shape': 
[None, None]}, 'compile_config': {'optimizer': 'adam', 'loss': {'module': 'modeling', 'class_name': 'CustomNonPaddingTokenLoss', 'config': {'name': 'custom_ner_loss', 'reduction': 'sum'}, 'registered_name': 'CustomNonPaddingTokenLoss'}, 'loss_weights': None, 'metrics': None, 'weighted_metrics': None, 'run_eagerly': False, 'steps_per_execution': 1, 'jit_compile': False}}.

Exception encountered: Unable to revive model from config. When overriding the `get_config()` method, make sure that the returned config contains all items used as arguments in the  constructor to <class 'modeling.NERModel'>, which is the default behavior. You can override this default behavior by defining a `from_config(cls, config)` class method to specify how to create an instance of NERModel from its config.

Received config={'trainable': True, 'dtype': 'float32'}

Error encountered during deserialization: NERModel.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'trainable'

Below is my NER model code and I face no problem when training.
import os
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import layers

class TransformerBlock(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, num_heads, ff_dim, rate=0.1):
        super().__init__()
        self.att = keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(
            num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim
        )
        self.ffn = keras.Sequential(
            [
                keras.layers.Dense(ff_dim, activation="relu"),
                keras.layers.Dense(embed_dim),
            ]
        )
        self.layernorm1 = keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.layernorm2 = keras.layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.dropout1 = keras.layers.Dropout(rate)
        self.dropout2 = keras.layers.Dropout(rate)

    def call(self, inputs, training=False):
        attn_output = self.att(inputs, inputs)
        attn_output = self.dropout1(attn_output, training=training)
        out1 = self.layernorm1(inputs + attn_output)
        ffn_output = self.ffn(out1)
        ffn_output = self.dropout2(ffn_output, training=training)
        return self.layernorm2(out1 + ffn_output)

class TokenAndPositionEmbedding(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, maxlen, vocab_size, embed_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.token_emb = keras.layers.Embedding(
            input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=embed_dim
        )
        self.pos_emb = keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=maxlen, output_dim=embed_dim)

    def call(self, inputs):
        maxlen = tf.shape(inputs)[-1]
        positions = tf.range(start=0, limit=maxlen, delta=1)
        position_embeddings = self.pos_emb(positions)
        token_embeddings = self.token_emb(inputs)
        return token_embeddings + position_embeddings
    
class NERModel(keras.Model):
    def __init__(
        self, num_tags, vocab_size, maxlen=1000, embed_dim=32, num_heads=2, ff_dim=32
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.embedding_layer = TokenAndPositionEmbedding(maxlen, vocab_size, embed_dim)
        self.transformer_block = TransformerBlock(embed_dim, num_heads, ff_dim)
        self.dropout1 = layers.Dropout(0.1)
        self.ff = layers.Dense(ff_dim, activation="relu")
        self.dropout2 = layers.Dropout(0.1)
        self.ff_final = layers.Dense(num_tags, activation="softmax")

    def call(self, inputs, training=False):
        x = self.embedding_layer(inputs)
        x = self.transformer_block(x)
        x = self.dropout1(x, training=training)
        x = self.ff(x)
        x = self.dropout2(x, training=training)
        x = self.ff_final(x)
        return x

class CustomNonPaddingTokenLoss(keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, reduction='sum', name="custom_ner_loss"):
        super().__init__(reduction=reduction, name=name)

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        loss_fn = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
            from_logits=False, reduction=self.reduction  # Pass the reduction argument here
        )
        loss = loss_fn(y_true, y_pred)
        mask = tf.cast((y_true > 0), dtype=tf.float32)
        loss = loss * mask
        return tf.reduce_sum(loss) / tf.reduce_sum(mask)
    
def save_model(model, filepath):
    if os.path.exists(filepath):
        filepath = filepath[:-6] + "1" + filepath[-6:]
    model.save(filepath)

When I try to run predict and load the trained model, the error above shows up. I tried to change the save type (h5) but there are a different error, therefore I change back to .keras file and try to solve this first.
import re
import pickle
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from data_preprocess import map_record_to_training_data
from modeling import CustomNonPaddingTokenLoss
    
def lookup(tokens):
    # Load the list from the file
    with open('./resources/vocabulary.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        loaded_list = pickle.load(f)
    # The StringLookup class will convert tokens to token IDs
    lookup_layer = keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=loaded_list)

    return lookup_layer(tokens)

def format_datatype(data):
    tokens =  [re.sub(r'[;,]', '', d) for d in data.split(' ')]
    #default is 0, since is for prediction
    ner_tags = [0 for d in data.split(' ')]

    #tab to separate
    string_input = str(len(tokens))+ "\t"+ "\t".join(tokens)+ "\t"+ "\t".join(map(str, ner_tags))
    string_input = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([string_input])


    finalize_input = (string_input.map(map_record_to_training_data)
                      .map(lambda x, y: (lookup(x),  y))
                      .padded_batch(1)
                      )

    return finalize_input

def prediction(data):
    # Load model
    # Load the model
    loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("./resources/trained_model/ner_model.keras", 
                                        custom_objects={'CustomNonPaddingTokenLoss': CustomNonPaddingTokenLoss})

    print(loaded_model.summary())
    all_predicted_tag_ids = []

    for x, _ in data:
        print("Input Tensor Info:")
        print("Data Type:", x.dtype)
        print("Shape:", x.shape)
        output = loaded_model(x, training=False)
        predictions = np.argmax(output, axis=-1)
        predictions = np.reshape(predictions, [-1])
        all_predicted_tag_ids.append(predictions)

    all_predicted_tag_ids = np.concatenate(all_predicted_tag_ids)

    ner_labels = ["[PAD]", "N", "M", "other"]
    mapping =  dict(zip(range(len(ner_labels)), ner_labels))
    predicted_tags = [mapping[tag] for tag in all_predicted_tag_ids]

    return predicted_tags


sample_input = "Hi, my name is David"
print(result)
print(sample_input.split(' '))
print(len(result))


As your error message says you need to implement a get_config() method.  This lets tensorflow know how to reinstantiate it.
def get_config(self):
    config = super().get_config()
    config.update({
        'ff_dim': self.ff_dim,
        etc.
    })
    return config

@classmethod
def from_config(cls, config):
    return cls(**config)

